# High fan speed and noise after system wakeup in newly install 13.04

Tags: suspend, fan, compaq

I've just installed ubuntu 13.04 on my notebook Compaq 6720s and found the cpu fun working at high speed after waking system up. 
When the system  is booted the fan works normaly and realy calm. But after sleep and waking up fan is really noisy.
I hadn't this problem with ubuntu 12.10.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found solution for my Compaq 6720s fan and Ubuntu 13.04 [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1094722/comments/22):

Create the file ”/etc/pm/sleep.d/99fancontrol.sh”, insert the code below and chmod 755 it. 
Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#

case "$1" in
 hibernate|suspend)
  # Stopping is not required.
  ;;
 thaw|resume)
# In background.
    echo -n 0 > /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state;
    sleep 2
    echo -n 0 > /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device1/cur_state;
    sleep 2
    echo -n 0 > /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device2/cur_state;

  ;;
 *) exit $NA
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if someone could explain what this is doing. I don't have fan problems so much as my CPU gets really hot after suspend. Running 13.04 on a lenovo thinkpad x131e. I'm loath to use the script as i don't know what it does and it if pertains to the fan then i might overheat my machine by switching it off.

Answer (score 1):

For my "HP 2510p" is high fan speed everytime so I run it on start too:

```
cd /etc/init.d
ln -s {source_path}/99fancontrol.sh
update-rc.d 99fancontrol.sh defaults
```

Also device is set to multiple inputs "cooling_device0 ~ 6" - 6 is 30%, all to zero means 0% speed - and at the same time temperature controller works too so when temperature is high set on of these inputs automatically.

***File:*** 99fancontrol.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
 hibernate|suspend)
  ;;
 start|thaw|resume)
 ( 
  sleep 5 ; 
  echo -n "0" > /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state; 
  echo -n "0" > /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device1/cur_state; 
  echo -n "0" > /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device2/cur_state; 
  echo -n "0" > /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device3/cur_state; 
  echo -n "0" > /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device4/cur_state; 
  echo -n "0" > /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device5/cur_state; 
  echo -n "1" > /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device6/cur_state;
 ) &
  ;;
 *) exit $NA
  ;;
esac
```

***Ref:*** [Fabrizio](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-source-2.6.17/+bug/77370)